# Store widget object state to an ipython kernel object instance rather than the object class

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Following the [stateful widget tutorial](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Custom.html#Making-the-widget-stateful), we can create a simple DOM widget. Here is the python code:

```py
import ipywidgets.widgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode

class HelloWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('HelloView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('hello').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
    value = Unicode('Hello World!').tag(sync=True)
```

And the javascript code:

```
%%javascript
require.undef('hello');

define('hello', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {

    var HelloView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        render: function() {
            this.el.textContent = this.model.get('value');
        },
    });

    return {
        HelloView : HelloView
    };
});
```

This works as advertised in the notebook:

```
In [1]: HelloWidget()
Out [1]: Hello World!
```

Now, if I want to store the widget `value` state to the object instance, I can change the python code so it looks like the following:

```py
import ipywidgets.widgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode

class HelloWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('HelloView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('hello').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
    def __init__(self, s):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = Unicode(s).tag(sync=True)
```

However, this does not work; the state is not rendered to the output cell as expected (no output):

```
In [1]: HelloWidget("Hello World!")
Out [1]:
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out (and feel a bit dumb).

The `trailets.Unicode` object is a descriptor, so it has to be attached to the class object, `HelloWidget`. So the correct code is as follows:

```
import ipywidgets.widgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode

class HelloWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('HelloView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('hello').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
    value = Unicode().tag(sync=True) # value is set to an empty string as placeholder

    def __init__(self, s):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = s # initialize with a value here
```